# Find best circular permutation that minimizes average distance between 2 ordered lists of points

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Given 2 ordered sets of n points each, A and B, how do I find the best circular permutation which minimizes the average pairwise-distance (using the distance of your choice) between points.

In other words, how do I algorithmically find `k` such that it minimizes `sum(||A[i] - B[(i + k) % n||)` with `0 <= k < n`? (I have omitted the division by `n` because minimizing the total distance should yield the same result as the mean I believe).

One extra requirement is that the algorithm should be usable in N-Dimensional spaces so I can't just sort the arrays.

I could obviously compute every pairwise distance but that would yield O(n^2) (n x n pairwise distance computation + n accumulations) complexity which is sub-optimal ([edit] I mean here that I sure hope one can do better than brute force).

Application:
One application is in graphics where I want to map each point of a shape to a point of another shape without creating crossing edges. See drawing below where we map each point of the red shape to a point on the blue shape.
[image: shape_points_mapping]

Comment: How do you know that it is sub-optimal? Do you know a faster algorithm?

Comment: @Stef I don't so perhaps this is the best exact solution. I just hope this is not. I would imagine one could find some approximate solution in better time than brute force but I am not so sure how to proceed. 
I could try and find the smallest pair-wise distance and then start some sort of gradient descent from there, but will this yield the best solution?

Comment: What is your domain? Euclidean space? Vector space? What is your metric?

Comment: I specifically work in 3-D euclidian space but I would imagine the algorithm wouldn't change much with the norm you use, would it? A norm is a norm.

Comment: Why the requirement that the permutation must be "circular"? What would happen if, for example, on your 2D picture above the points would be enumerated in a different order, or if the shape was 3D?

Comment: So the way I create "Edges" Is through the ordering of the points. This means that changing the order of points will change the connectivity of the points and thus the final shape.

Comment: More generally, independantly of my implementation, if you look at the drawing, if now say you were to map point 1 to k+1 and point 2 to k, you would now have crossing edges, no matter how you define the edges.

Comment: As a side note, if I could simply look for the best allocation without the ciruclar buffer I could use [the Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) or perhaps some [graph matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)) perhaps. But the added constraint is annoying me.

Comment: So, are we just talking about [simple, closed polygonal chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain) here? And you just want to match two such chains together?

Comment: That's correct yes. This could be reformulated as such

Comment: Would you be happy to minimize the sum of squared distances instead? The square root tucked away inside the norm makes it hard to fathom a fast algorithm.

Comment: That's actually a very good idea. I don't think the square root here would change much to the desired solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two ideas.

If you're willing to optimize the sum of *squares* of distances, then there's an O(n log n) time algorithm based on fast convolution. The modified objective allows us to find the contribution of each coordinate separately for each possible rotation. Then we sum element-wise and choose the best.

To solve the reduced problem in 1D: we want

```
sum_i (A[i] - B[(i+k) mod n])**2
```

for each `k`. Do some algebra:

```
sum_i (A[i] - B[(i+k) mod n])**2 =
sum_i (A[i]**2 - 2*A[i]*B[(i+k) mod n] + B[(i+k) mod n]**2) =
sum_i A[i]**2 + sum_i B[i]**2 - 2*sum_i (A[i]*B[(i+k) mod n]).
```

The first two terms are the same for all `k`, so just compute them. The vector of third terms for all `k` can be computed quickly in bulk as a constant times `A` convolved with the reverse of `B`.

---

My second idea is a recursive heuristic. If `n` is small, just brute force it. Otherwise, make a smaller instance by computing the midpoint of each pair of consecutive points in each list. Recursively align these. Then multiply the heuristic rotation by two and check it against the rotations one up and one down from it. In constant dimensions, this yields a recurrence like T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n), which is O(n).

Comment: I don't think the first method is really that much faster actually. Developing the square method is a good idea but in the end, even if you disregard the first term and try and minimize `-2*sum (A[i] * B[(i +k) %n]` you will still have to do this for all k and i so that is still n^2 operations.
The second idea on the other hand seems like a very interesting lead to me. I'll try and implement it and keep you updated. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Niels computing it for one particular k would cost O(n) time, but the convolution would compute all n rotations in O(n log n) time.

Comment: Why is `sum_i A[i]**2` equal to `sum_i B[i]**2`?

Comment: @STF It isn't, good catch. The important part was that we can extricate `k` from those terms.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I apologies but I think in both cases I am going to need more help.

- Case 2, if I have n points, if I take the midpoints of each, I have n-1 points. So it will take me n - 2 recursions to get to the trivial case of 2 points. At each recursion level I have 2 tests to make, which means 2 * (n - l) operations where l is the recursion level. Overall this makes `sum_l_from_0_to_n-2( 2 * (n - l)) = (n-1)(n+2) = O(n^2)`
-in Case 1, I have troubles seeing where the O(n log n) comes from...I mean `sum_i (A[i]*B[(i+k) mod n])` costs n and you still have to test all n possibilities?

Comment: @Niels For idea 1, if you just evaluate that formula directly it's indeed going to be quadratic. My point is that it's amenable to a [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform), which achieves a significant speedup by sharing work between different values of k. For idea 2, I meant take every other midpoint.